# Program for the discriminant of a quadratic equation

Tags: java, complex-numbers

Write a **method calculateRoots** which takes as input 3 doubles, representing the quadratic, linear, and constant terms of a quadratic equation and returns a ComplexNumber[] representing the roots of the equation.

1. If the discriminant b^2 - 4ac is a positive number, then there are 2 real roots. You should create anew ComplexNumber[] of size 2 and put two ComplexNumbers into it, each of which have a complexcomponent with value of 0 (and the real components set to be the roots). For consistency, put the smaller of the 2 roots first.
2. If the discriminant is 0, then there is just one root. Since the return type of a method is always the same, you still should create a new ComplexNumber[], just of size one and put a ComplexNumber with appropriate real value set and a complex component of 0.
3. If the discriminant is less than 0, then there are 2 roots, each of which have non-zero complex components. Solve for the individual pieces and store them into 2 ComplexNumbers which are then put into one array.

I have done the following. I was already having a hard time solving the question therefore I would like someone to tell me where I have gone wrong, since the program kept showing a compiler error.

This is a **JAVA** program!

Any sort of hint will help. Thank you for your kind time and help.

```
public static complexNumber[] coomplexNumbers(double a, double b, double c){
  if (a==0&&b==0&&c==0){ //All values are roots
 return null; 
  }
  else if (a==0&&b==0){ //no roots
 return new complexNumber[0]; 
  }
  else if (a==0){ 
 return new complexNumber[]{-c/b}; /
  }
  else{
 double discriminant= b*b-4*a*c;
 if (discriminant < 0) 

  return new complexNumber[0]; 
     else if (discriminant==0) 

   return new complexNumber[]{ (-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a)};
     else 

  return new complexNumber[]{
      (-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a),
      (-b - Math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a)
  }
 }
    }
```

Comment: The compile error should give you a line number for the error.  What line?  I can tell from looking, but you should learn to read the compiler errors.

Comment: Also, if you use an integrated development environment, errors like this will be highlighted in red.  Here is a good free one:  http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

Comment: Copy-paste the compiler error.

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 1):

One problem I can see is with the following -

```
return new complexNumber[]{ (-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a)};
```

the result of `(-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a)` is not a `complexNumber`.

An array of `complexNumber` should have instance of `complexNumber`.